# NUXT: Using async fetch as mixin, how to access page data to overwrite

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I have a masthead component that I've been using in pages and since they get destroyed on page change, I've decided to move the component up into the layout so that during route change, it persists (and I can animate/transition accordingly). I am using VueX to update the content of the masthead (imagery, copy, etc...).

Right now I am using an async fetch in all of the pages to make the appropriate call to the store (to update or hide the masthead).

I would like to eventually move the fetch into a mixin and import it to each page versus having to place it in each page manually. The question is, I want to use the mixin to retrieve some page specific data before the call is made. I can always default it in the mixin, but when it comes to overwriting from within the page - I can't access the page data() or asyncData() from fetch().

What would be the best way to access page specific data in fetch()?

My mixin:

```
export default {
  data() {
     return {
        masthead: false
     }
  },
  async fetch({ state }) {
    await state.commit('masthead/UPDATE_MASTHEAD', this.masthead);
  }
}
```

In Page:
import masthead from '~/mixins/masthead'

```
export default {
  name: 'homepage',
  mixins: [masthead]
  data() {
     // Why can't I access this in fetch
     return {
       masthead: true
     };
  },
  asyncData() {
     // Why can't I access this in fetch?
     return {
       masthead: true
     };
  },
```

Thanks!